# I need to limit label.Text to a max 6 integers

Tags: vb.net

I have label16 that had value `1230456.8987` I just want that if the value is more than 6 numbers, it will turn to `12304.....`

```
Private Sub Label16_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label16.TextChanged
  Label16.Text = Left(Label16.Text, 6)
End Sub
```

Comment: That's just silly. The user can't type into a `Label`. The only way that text can get into a `Label` is if you put it there using code so don't put text into the `Label` in the first place if you don't want it there. You need to put some thought into what you're doing. Where is this data coming from and how does it get into the `Label` in the first place? That is where you need to place the appropriate code to validate and/or process any data you're using.

Comment: The value gets from the database

Comment: So fix it when you get it. Problem solved. the `Label` is irrelevant.

Comment: If you use DataBindings, the `Binding` class has a `Format` and `Parse` events that you can use to format the data content both inbound and outbound. So, don't use `[Control].DataBindings.Add(...)`, but create a Binding, subscribe to the events that you need (probably `Format`), then add the Binding object using `[Control].DataBindings.Add([Binding])`. You can then `.SubString()` the inbound value,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
If You don't know how to do it from the database.

Maybe not that fancy but it works

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim s As String = Label16.Text
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(s)
        sb(5) = "."c
        sb(6) = "."c
        sb(7) = "."c
        sb(8) = "."c
        sb(9) = "."c
        sb(10) = "."c
        sb(11) = "."c
        Dim newS As String = sb.ToString()
        Label16.Text = sb.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```